# HTTP Tracing from server perspective

Tags: http, go, server, trace

In Go 1.7 http tracing was introduced, but it works only from client perspective. Is it possible somehow trace request from server perspective, I mean I want to add some hooks, for example when connection was established. Should it be implemented as middleware or what?

```
http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for server-side tracing was added a lot earlier, in [Go 1.3](https://golang.org/doc/go1.3#minor_library_changes). Create your own [`http.Server`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server), and set a callback function in the `Server.ConnState` field.

```
// ConnState specifies an optional callback function that is
// called when a client connection changes state. See the
// ConnState type and associated constants for details.
ConnState func(net.Conn, ConnState) // Go 1.3
```

[`http.ConnState`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ConnState) details when / what connection states the callback is notified about.

```
// StateNew represents a new connection that is expected to
// send a request immediately. Connections begin at this
// state and then transition to either StateActive or
// StateClosed.
StateNew ConnState = iota

// StateActive represents a connection that has read 1 or more
// bytes of a request. The Server.ConnState hook for
// StateActive fires before the request has entered a handler
// and doesn't fire again until the request has been
// handled. After the request is handled, the state
// transitions to StateClosed, StateHijacked, or StateIdle.
// For HTTP/2, StateActive fires on the transition from zero
// to one active request, and only transitions away once all
// active requests are complete. That means that ConnState
// cannot be used to do per-request work; ConnState only notes
// the overall state of the connection.
StateActive

// StateIdle represents a connection that has finished
// handling a request and is in the keep-alive state, waiting
// for a new request. Connections transition from StateIdle
// to either StateActive or StateClosed.
StateIdle

// StateHijacked represents a hijacked connection.
// This is a terminal state. It does not transition to StateClosed.
StateHijacked

// StateClosed represents a closed connection.
// This is a terminal state. Hijacked connections do not
// transition to StateClosed.
StateClosed
```

A simple example:

```
srv := &http.Server{
    Addr: ":8080",
    ConnState: func(conn net.Conn, cs http.ConnState) {
        fmt.Println("Client:", conn.RemoteAddr(), "- new state:", cs)
    },
}
log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())
```

Making a request to the above server:

```
curl localhost:8080
```

Server output will be:

```
Client: 127.0.0.1:39778 - new state: new
Client: 127.0.0.1:39778 - new state: active
Client: 127.0.0.1:39778 - new state: idle
Client: 127.0.0.1:39778 - new state: closed
```